# Why doesn't the HTML form variable seem to transfer to the JS function?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've been working on this assignment for a while, and basically all it has to do is compare sorting algorithms and their number of comparisons. It should ask for a number from the user and that will be the array size to sort. However it seems the variable does not get passed and ends up being undefined as proven when I try and print it at "test2". I tried having an OnClick to a function that assigns the element as you may see, but I abandoned that idea. And I have to admit I'm pretty new to this. But any help would be appreciated!! Thank you!!

```
<html>
  <title>Assignment 2</title>
  <body>
    <h2>Assignment 2</h2>
    <form id="form" method="GET" action="">
  Choose an amount of numbers to sort: <input type="number" name="sorter" id="choice" max="500" min="0"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<button type="button" id="InsertionSort" onclick="insertionSort()">Insertion Sort</button>
<button type="button" id="QuickSort" onclick="quickSort()">Quick Sort</button>
<button type="button" id="BubbleSort" onclick="bubbleSort()">Bubble Sort</button>
<button type="button" id="MergeSort" onclick="mergeSort()">Merge Sort</button>
<p id="test"></p>
<p id="test2"></p>
<p id="insertion"></p>
<p id="insertionCount"></p>

<script>
  //var input;
  //function assign(element)
  //{
  //  input = element.value;
  //  return input;
  //}
  function insertionSort()
{
  var input = document.getElementById("choice").value;
  var comparisons = 0;
  var arr = Array(input);
  document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = input;
  for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
  {
    arr[k] = Math.random() * 1000;
  }...etc.
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I shouldn't be helping you with your homework... But it seems to work. Just push the sort button and not the submit button. And it will print the number on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community. :) It's a challenging, but fun world.

I've got a working snippet of your code above. I'm not entirely sure what you're wanting to do from here, but the input is in scope of the function you've got. Small syntactical errors prevented it from running properly initially, but you should be good now.

```html
<html>
  <title>Assignment 2</title>
  <body>
    <h2>Assignment 2</h2>
    <form id="form" method="GET" action="">
  Choose an amount of numbers to sort: <input type="number" name="sorter" id="choice" max="500" min="0"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<button type="button" id="InsertionSort" onclick="insertionSort()">Insertion Sort</button>
<button type="button" id="QuickSort" onclick="quickSort()">Quick Sort</button>
<button type="button" id="BubbleSort" onclick="bubbleSort()">Bubble Sort</button>
<button type="button" id="MergeSort" onclick="mergeSort()">Merge Sort</button>
<p id="test"></p>
<p id="test2"></p>
<p id="insertion"></p>
<p id="insertionCount"></p>

<script>
  function insertionSort() {
    var input = document.getElementById("choice").value;
    console.log(input); // prints out string version of number
    console.log(Number(input)) // prints out numeric version of number

    var comparisons = 0;
    var arr = Array(input);
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = input;
    for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
    {
      arr[k] = Math.random() * 1000;
    }
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```